# Nifi: how to use folderFilter for fetching files from S3

Tags: apache-nifi, hortonworks-data-platform, cloudera-cdh

I have a requirement to access AWS S3 bucket through NIFI and process files into HDFS from the specific subfolder Ex:- S3 bucket name: my_bucket. Folders under my_bucket(S3) ABC, BDE,CEF. I have to process files only from BDE subfolder and ignore form ABC & CEF.

I am currently using ListS3 -> Fetch S3 -> Routeonattribute -> UpdateAttribute -> PutHDFS

I am unable to filter folder name on ListS3 or FetchS3. So thought of using Routeonattribute by filtering on absolute.path as below. Could you please help if the above logic is correct?
${absolute.path:contains('DBE')}

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the folder in ListS3 using the property prefix
Provide the required folder name in prefix. ex: BDE/
It'll append with bucket name

As a result it'll list the files present in BUCKET_NAME/PREFIX

Comment: Thanks for this, had to dig way too hard to accomplish this.   I wish the prefix section was right up next to the bucket section.  Seems like they're pretty closely related and would make sense to be more co-located.